# problem in Jquery .html()

Tags: jquery, html

when i use this code this is not work. i think this problem has occurred for double quotation sign

my html value is loading from database and i can not change double quotation to other thing

```
$('#infobox .information').html('<br><div style="text-align: left;">TEXT</div><br>');
```

thanks

edit :: i found problem

when my text have break line this source not work

like this :

```
$('#infobox .information').html('
hello
world
');
```

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/De33q/

Comment: Can you show how you're loading it?

Comment: And what is the problem? *does not work* is not an error description. If you want help you have to put a bit more effort into your question.

Comment: @yoda :

i load from database by $text

Comment: You need to explain why this code does not work.  Using the code you provided I see no error, whatever selector I use the html() jQuery function with replaces its content with the HTML code you provide, no issues with the double quotes, either.

Comment: please provide the DOM, double quote are fine the only rule is:  If you are using one form of quote in the string, you might want to use the other as the literal

Comment: @ebad g noone here has a non-magical way to find what `$text` is, so please help us helping you.

Comment: @Felix Kling :

not load text and when add in my code other jquery function is not work too but when i remove this part, my code is work correctly

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that demonstrates your problem. As others said, the code you have given works. If you don't add more information, we cannot help you.

Comment: @ebad gh That is still not helpful - we need more information about the page this code is going into (as JohnJohnGa states) we need more information about the DOM structure this code operates on, and the conditions under which this code is being called.  As you present it, there are no issues.  There is an issue in the logic you use to invoke this code, and you need to help us to figure out what that issue is or where it is.

Comment: Again, we need to see the DOM (HTML tree - something like <div id="infobox"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#infobox .information').html('

hello
world
');
```

You can't have a line break in the middle of a string. If you do want a line break, you can do this:

```
$('#infobox .information').html(

'hello'+
' world'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me http://jsfiddle.net/X5dgr/

Comment: -1 you answer to the question without take a look at all the details, how you can know the DOM structure?

Comment: it's not my fault he didn't post the enough of his code. The dom structure is #element .otherElement as per is post. take a look at his pre edit code.

Comment: so you should wait until he will give more details

Comment: my answer is still correct and still valid give his original answer given that the OP stated _when i use this code this is not work. i think this problem has occurred for double quotation sign_ my post does answer his question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your HTML value - the double quotes are perfectly normal.

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxpdr/).

I couldn't, of course, replicate your `('#infobox .information')` so you will have to provide more info if this doesn't help.

Comment: I will not downvote because you are correct but I dont think it s a good answer due to the low level of details in the question, your answer should be a comment